# Problem with Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I've got error on this line `$number = "$autonumber[0]/$automonth/$autoyear/proforma";`.
This is error: https://flareapp.io/share/qm1WG17d
I am trying to make function witch will be adding number of proform in month to other data. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Anybody help me?

This is controller with this function witch generates error:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $autoyear = date('Y');
    $automonth = date('m');

    $autonumber = DB::table('proforms')
        ->select(DB::raw('MAX(autonumber) as autonumber'))
        ->where('automonth', '=', '$automonth')
        ->where('autoyear', '=', '$autoyear')
        ->get();
    $autonumber[0]++;
    $number = "$autonumber[0]/$automonth/$autoyear/proforma";
    DB::table('proforms')->insert(
        ['autonumber' => $number, 'automonth' => $automonth, 'autoyear' => $autoyear]
    );

    request()->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'proformdate' => 'required',
        'selldate' => 'required',
        'paymentmethod' => 'required',
        'paymentdate' => 'required',
        'status' => 'nullable',
        'city' => 'nullable',
        'comments' => 'nullable',
        'name' => 'required',
        'PKWIU' => 'nullable',
        'quantity' => 'required',
        'unit' => 'required',
        'netunit' => 'required',
        'nettotal' => 'required',
        'VATrate' => 'required',
        'grossunit' => 'required',
        'grosstotal' => 'required',

    ]);

    Proform::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('proforms.index')
        ->with('success', 'Proform created successfully.');
}
```

After dd($autonumber);
I get:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1328 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1324 ▼
      +"autonumber": null
    }
  ]
}
```

After print_r($autonumber);

```
  Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [autonumber] => ) ) )
```

Comment: `print_r($autonumber)` to see what is it.

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [autonumber] => ) ) )

Comment: either you use `->value('autonumber')` or still use `->get()` and reach the inner dimension `$autonumber[0]->autonumber`

Comment: Please share the error message in your question, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Did my answer help your problem, else i will gladly debug it with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding, the following code will not return an integer, but an object which has the following structure: `{"autonumber": 42}`.

```
$autonumber = DB::table('proforms')
    ->select(DB::raw('MAX(autonumber) as autonumber'))
    ->where('automonth', '=', '$automonth')
    ->where('autoyear', '=', '$autoyear')
    ->get();
```

Change the code to work with that structure.

```
$autonumber[0]->autonumber++;
$number = $autonumber[0]->autonumber;
$number = "$number/$automonth/$autoyear/proforma";
```